# How to enumerate in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a method that looks like this:

```
static inline float average(int numbers, ...) {

}
```

How do you use for loop to get all the value I've put into numbers. For example:

```
average(1, 3, 5, 7);
```

Comment: Look into [variadic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)

Comment: There is only one value in `numbers`. No need for a loop. Please state your problem and provide a [mcve].

Comment: You mean function, not method.  C doesn't have classes, so it doesn't have methods.

Comment: @Olaf I do have the `, ...` part

Comment: @TomShen: That is not related to `numbers`, though. Variable arguments are a very different concept than e.g. Python's `list` type and missusing them is a very bad idea. Among other issues, you completely loose type-safety with varaidic functions. This is the road to disaster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. If you want to use variadic arguments, you need a mechanism for getting the number of arguments. Most often it is inferred from the first non-variadic argument. That's how `printf` and family work for instance.

For your example I personally wouldn't bother with variadic arguments. If you want a mathematical function like `average` applied to one or more arguments, just use a vector:

```
static inline float average(const int* numbers, int size)
```

---

If you insist in using variadic functions, these will get you started:

- [GNU introduction and example for variadic function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html)
- [Wikipedia entry on Variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)
- [cppreference documentation with example for C variadic functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic)